# How to check if a variable is a numeric value?

Tags: php

PHP PDO's lastInsertId() method actually returns an numeric value, but it may also return something completely different like some strange SQLSTATE code or whatever. In any case it returns not a numeric value I would like to log an error. Is there a way to safely check for that?

Comment: *Really?!* You posted 4 questions in the last hour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
is_int($value)
```

or

```
is_numeric($value)
```

Answer (score 6):

[`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric) returns *true* for numerical strings and *false* otherwise. A similar function is [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit).

Answer (score 0):

`is_int` or `is_numeric` is a good way.

You can also try to cast result to `(int)` and check if it is `> 0`.