# How to check if variable is Alphabetic or Numeric in PHP?

Tags: php

How to check if variable is Alphabetic or Numeric in PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969464/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-numeric-value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on how you define *numeric*, you'll use one of the following functions :

- [**`is_numeric`**](https://www.php.net/is_numeric)
- [**`ctype_digit`**](https://www.php.net/ctype_digit)

With the first one, numeric is defined as *(quoting)* :

> Numeric strings consist of optional
> sign, any number of digits, optional
> decimal part and optional exponential
> part.

While, with the second one, you will *(quoting)* :

> Checks if all of the characters in the
> provided string, text, are numerical

And, for alphabetic, you'll be interested by :

- [**`ctype_alpha`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)

Quoting :

> Checks if all of the characters in the
> provided string, text, are alphabetic.
> In the standard C locale letters are
> just `[A-Za-z]`

And, as pointed out by *@Long Ears* in his comment, if you want to check both in a single shot, you'll find the [**`ctype_alnum()`**][1] function *(quoting)* :

> Checks if all of the characters in the
> provided string, text, are
> alphanumeric.

In any case, you might want to take a look at the full list of [**Ctype functions**][2].

Comment: For either alphabetic or numeric, `ctype_alnum`, or if you need to support unicode then `preg_match('/^[\pL\d]+\z/', $s)`

Answer (score 4):

Use the [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/is_numeric) function:

```
is_numeric("42");           // true
is_numeric(1337);           // true
is_numeric("1e4");          // true
is_numeric("not numeric");  // false
is_numeric(Array());        // false
is_numeric(9.1);            // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) or [ctype_alpha()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) functions

Answer (score 0):

```
you quick test the input val by if numeric or alpha`enter code here`
using this php function 
if(ctype_alnum($eafrik)){ 
  echo "is alphatnumeric"; 
}else{ 
  echo "is not alphanumeric" 
}
```

Comment: Well done, this deserves to be the answer.