# how to validate numeric strings in PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for a method that would allow me to check for valid IDs in my system.

They're by definition:

- positive, not 0,
- a whole number, but might be bigger than integer size
- come as either string or number

I'd like to know what you think is the most elegant way of validating this. Candidates that fail are:

- `is_int()`, because it's valid for negative numbers, AND because of the integer size limit
- `is_numeric()`, because it'd valid for float, or, say, having an exponential part like this +0123.45e6
- `ctype_digit()` with casting the input to string, because this would be valid: "0000"

I've so far settled with this:

```
preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*$/',(string)$id);
```

Can anyone come up with an alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969464/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-numeric-value

Comment: not quite: the real kicker is the "bigger than int" while still a whole number. It could apply to the person asking in the other thread, though, if his tables get real big.

Comment: Note: I'm aware that creating a function, combining various methods, is a possibility (which I'm using in practice, I don't expose the regexp every time), I'm wondering if PHP is offering me something more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [filter_var](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) functions with [FILTER_VALIDATE_INT](http://no.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php). For valid integers you can specify ranges.Probably has the same limitaton with the size limit, but for that you'll have to build a custom function that serve exactly your requirements.

Comment: I guess I could wrap it in filter var, like:

Comment: I guess I could wrap it in filter_var, like: `filter_var((string) $id, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => '/^[1-9][0-9]*$/')) )`; probably a good idea when that's a project-wide validation approach (which it isn't right now)

Comment: my real question is why are you using id with INT over the INT limits? this will turn against you at some point. Use another combination of key if you need more keys

Comment: The definition of the id is outside of my control. That said, I'm not "using id with INT" over its limits; it's not INT at all, just a whole number as a string. I wildly guess it has something to do with id pools and distributed servers and stuff. Mainly with stuff, though.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
function vaild_id($passed_value=-1)
{
    if((is_int($passed_value)) && ($passed_value > 0)) return true;
    else return false; 
}
```

this will also allow you to add other rules to it if you need to

- notes:
  is_int [and php] have a limit on the total size of integers allowed depending on if your working on 32 or 64bit so do that that into account
  [php.net comment on is_int about system bit environment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php#97006)

Comment: And what about integer size limit: `is_int( 2147483648 );// false`?

Comment: added note about is_int size limit

Comment: yes, it's of no use if it limits me to the size of int, be that 32 or 64 bit environments